# Impossible to run the program with the "mpirun" command

Tags: cpu

I perfectly builded a program with cygwin, however when i've to run the .exe file with the command "mpirun" as the tutorial of the program says

https://github.com/jalombar/starsmasher/blob/master/documentation/walkthroughs/star_star_flyby.md

It appears the following error:

```
    $ mpirun -np 4 test_cpu_sph
[Francyrad:00524] PMIX ERROR: INIT in file /cygdrive/d/cyg_pub/devel/openmpi/v3.1/openmpi-3.1.5-1.x86_64/src/openmpi-3.1.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix2x/pmix/src/mca/gds/ds21/gds_ds21_lock_pthread.c at line 188
[Francyrad:00524] PMIX ERROR: SUCCESS in file /cygdrive/d/cyg_pub/devel/openmpi/v3.1/openmpi-3.1.5-1.x86_64/src/openmpi-3.1.5/opal/mca/pmix/pmix2x/pmix/src/mca/common/dstore/dstore_base.c at line 2432
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Open MPI tried to fork a new process via the "execve" system call but
failed.  Open MPI checks many things before attempting to launch a
child process, but nothing is perfect. This error may be indicative
of another problem on the target host, or even something as silly as
having specified a directory for your application. Your job will now
abort.

  Local host:        Francyrad
  Application name:  /cygdrive/c/Users/Francyrad/Desktop/starsmasher/GAM1.667_N1.5
  Error:             /cygdrive/c/Users/Francyrad/Desktop/starsmasher/GAM1.667_N1.5/test_cpu_sph
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun was unable to start the specified application as it encountered an
error:

Error name:
Node: (null)

when attempting to start process rank 34361314336.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
4 total processes failed to start
[Francyrad:00524] 3 more processes have sent help message help-orte-odls-default.txt / execve error
[Francyrad:00524] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

I tried everything, to change the syntaxis and other, but anything! Ive no idea how to make run this application. What the hell i've to do????

Answer (score 1):

Hum, the executable seem to be the problem...

Does your executable has been well built ? Do you see it with a "ls" command ? 
And did you try to call the executable with mpirun using "mpirun -np 4 ./test_cpu_sph" instead of "mpirun -np 4 test_cpu_sph" ?

And could you give a bit more information please ? (if you're using cygwin, I guess that you're running on Windows ?)